# Error connecting to Firebird with JDBC

Tags: jdbc, firebird, jaybird

I am trying to connect a Java application to a Firebird database (I don't have access to the source code).

The application requires Driver class, JDBC URL, Username and Password.
No matter what parameters I am passing, I am getting the following exception:

> Error trying to connect to 'jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/C:/Temp/employee.fdb': Specified properties contain reference to a DPB parameter under original and alias names: original name isc_dpb_password, alias : password

Comment: What is the JDBC URL you use to connect? It looks like you are setting the password both through the URL (with the short property name `password`), and through the `password` parameter of `DriverManager.getConnection`, or you are using two different properties for the password in the URL (`password` and `isc_dpb_password`), but that seems not very likely..

Comment: I do see something fishy in the code that checks for duplicate aliases, so I will investigate further. Is this an inhouse application, or something else that I can test myself?

Comment: Hi Mark, it is something else - third party application, so I am unable to check the source code. It is throwing the same Exception even when I don't pass the password. The exact URL is jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/C:/Temp/employee.fdb?lc_ctype=UTF8

Comment: Which Jaybird version are you using?

Comment: It is Jaybird-2.2.10-JDK_1.6

Comment: It is very possible, that the connection code sets both DPB parameters - isc_dpb_password and password.
Why is it necessary to check if parameters are used together - FBDriverPropertyManager.java, lines 190-207 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106606/discussion-between-dmateev-and-mark-rotteveel).